# Let $G$ be a graph on $10$ vertices of degrees $1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,8$. How many paths of length $2$ does $G$ contain?

Tags: graph-theory

I don't quite know how to begin with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any path of length two is uniquely determined by a couple of edges having a vetex in common. Now, count those in this way: choose the common vertex, and then choose a couple of edges having that vertex in common. Alternatively, compute the square of the adjacency matrix of $G$, and sum all of its entries.

Answer (score 3):

Every path of length $2$ of $G$ is of the form $u - v - w$, which is uniquely identified by the middle vertex $v$ and its two end vertices $u$ and $w$. To count the number of such paths, we only need to enumerate all possible middle points and the corresponding possible end points. For a middle point $v$, the number of corresponding paths of length $2$ is $\delta(v) \choose 2$, where $\delta(v)$ is the degree of $v$. Therefore, the answer is
$$
{1 \choose 2} + {1 \choose 2} + {2 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 2} + {3\choose 2}+ {3 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 2} + {4\choose 2} + {5\choose 2} + {8\choose 2}
$$